# Finding XY co-ordinates in an image openCV

Tags: opencv, coordinates

I was trying to find the XY co-ordinates of every component in a PCB board image using contours. But the contours are not exact for some components. I hope the contours wont work for what I am looking for. Any suggestions on this method or any new method other than contours are most welcome

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: if the contours are not exact enough, try a larger image, better resolution.

Comment: @berak the image has been taken through telecentric lens, 2040x1086

Comment: oook. did you calibrate it ? (maybe it's not the findContour's fault, but a distortion issue)

Comment: It would really help us to help you if you could post an example image.

Comment: http://s1344.photobucket.com/user/jakr3/media/telecentric_zps6c59d01c.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0    here is a sample image